# TreeView of objects having child nodes that are fields of the object

Tags: java, model-view-controller, javafx, data-binding, treeview

I have an object with fields of varying datatypes:

```
public class MyObject{
     private String field1;
     private CustomObject field2;
     private int field3;
     ...
}
```

I want to create a tree view of `MyObject` that will have multiple `MyObject` nodes, each with the fields (`field1`, `field2`, `field3`..etc) as children.

I know I can make a TreeView of Strings and populate it myself with an addNode(MyObject obj) method in which I would add the individual TreeItems I need. However, I did this with a TableView where I was able to bind a column with a field property. Such as:

```
TableView<MyObject> table;
TableColumn<MyObject, String> myColumn;
myColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("field1"));
```

Is there any way to do something similar for a `TreeView<MyObject>`? Im not opposed to creating a subclass that extends `TreeItem<?>`

The ending result I'm looking for would be something like this:

```
--> First My Object
    ->field1: "Value at Field 1"
    ->field2: "Value at Field 2"
    ->field3: 3
--> Second My Object
    ->field1: "Value at Field 1"
    ->field2: "Value at Field 2"
    ->field3: 3
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not think `TreeView` has this feature.

Comment: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/javafx-treeview-example/

Comment: @Sedrick not a good example, IMO - it's simply TreeItem<String>

Comment: I know. I am making an example.

Answer (score 5):

Pretty much any time you use a `TreeView` with different types in different nodes of the tree, you will need some casting and/or type checking somewhere.

One possible approach here is to subclass `TreeItem` to provide a field for the property you want to show, and then to use a `TreeCell` that shows the string value of that property.

Here's a very basic example of that:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TreeViewWithProperties extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        List<SomeEntity> entities = Arrays.asList(
                new SomeEntity("First object", "String value 1", 42),
                new SomeEntity("Second object", "String value 2", 3)
        );

        TreeView<SomeEntity> tree = new TreeView<>();
        tree.setShowRoot(false);

        TreeItem<SomeEntity> treeRoot = new TreeItem<>();
        tree.setRoot(treeRoot);


        for (SomeEntity entity : entities) {
            TreeItem<SomeEntity> item = PropertyTreeItem.baseItem(entity);
            treeRoot.getChildren().add(item);

            item.getChildren().add(new PropertyTreeItem<String>(entity, entity.getStringField()));
            item.getChildren().add(new PropertyTreeItem<Integer>(entity, entity.getValue()));
        }

        tree.setCellFactory(tv -> new TreeCell<SomeEntity>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(SomeEntity entity, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(entity, empty);
                PropertyTreeItem<?> item = (PropertyTreeItem<?>) getTreeItem();
                if (empty) {
                    setText(null);
                } else {
                    setText(item.getPropertyValue().toString());
                }
            }
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(tree);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static class PropertyTreeItem<T> extends TreeItem<SomeEntity> {

        private final T propertyValue ;

        public PropertyTreeItem(SomeEntity entity, T value) {
            super(entity);
            this.propertyValue = value ;
        }

        public static PropertyTreeItem<SomeEntity> baseItem(SomeEntity entity) {
            return new PropertyTreeItem<>(entity, entity);
        }

        public T getPropertyValue() {
            return propertyValue ;
        }
    }

    public class SomeEntity {

        private String name ;
        private String stringField ;
        private int value ;


        public SomeEntity(String name, String stringField, int value) {
            this.name = name;
            this.stringField = stringField;
            this.value = value;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String getStringField() {
            return stringField;
        }
        public void setStringField(String stringField) {
            this.stringField = stringField;
        }
        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }
        public void setValue(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return name ;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]

Some variations on this are possible, of course. If you wanted to use JavaFX properties in the entity class, and be able to change those values externally to the tree, you could bind the text to the property in the cell instead of simply setting it.

Comment: While I can see this helping someone, I dont think I need it that way since all of the fields will be appended to a string anyway, the conversion would be done. I was just hoping for a way to automate the creation of the child nodes.

Comment: @KevinFurlong Then  perhaps you could have asked that, instead of the question you actually asked.

Answer (score 0):

Using some ideas from the link I posted under your question. This example uses a helper Class to create the `TreeItems`.

> Main

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXApplication128 extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        MyObject myObject1 = new MyObject("myObject1", "field 1 a", new CustomObject("customObject 1", 3), 5);
        MyObject myObject2 = new MyObject("myObject2", "field 1 b", new CustomObject("customObject 2", 36), 10);
        MyObject myObject3 = new MyObject("myObject3", "field 1 c", new CustomObject("customObject 3", 23), 8);

        List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList();
        list.add(myObject1);
        list.add(myObject2);
        list.add(myObject3);

        List<TreeItem<String>> treeItemsContainer = new ArrayList();
        for (MyObject object : list) {
            ObjectToTreeView objectToTreeView = new ObjectToTreeView(object);
            treeItemsContainer.add(objectToTreeView.getRootItem());
        }

        TreeItem<String> rootItem = new TreeItem();
        rootItem.setExpanded(true);
        rootItem.getChildren().addAll(treeItemsContainer);

        TreeView treeView = new TreeView(rootItem);

        Scene scene = new Scene(treeView, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

> ObjectToTreeView Class <- a helper class

```
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class ObjectToTreeView
{

    private final TreeItem<String> rootItem = new TreeItem();

    public ObjectToTreeView(MyObject myObject)
    {
        rootItem.setValue(myObject.getTitle());

        rootItem.getChildren().add(new TreeItem(myObject.getField1()));
        CustomObject customObject = myObject.getField2();
        rootItem.getChildren().add(new TreeItem(customObject.getName()));
        rootItem.getChildren().add(new TreeItem(customObject.getNumber()));
        rootItem.getChildren().add(new TreeItem(myObject.getField3()));
    }

    /**
     * @return the rootItem
     */
    public TreeItem<String> getRootItem()
    {
        return rootItem;
    }

}
```

> MyObject Class

```
/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class MyObject
{

    private String title;
    private String field1;
    private CustomObject field2;
    private int field3;

    public MyObject(String title, String field1, CustomObject field2, int field3)
    {
        this.title = title;
        this.field1 = field1;
        this.field2 = field2;
        this.field3 = field3;
    }

    /**
     * @return the title
     */
    public String getTitle()
    {
        return title;
    }

    /**
     * @param title the title to set
     */
    public void setTitle(String title)
    {
        this.title = title;
    }

    /**
     * @return the field1
     */
    public String getField1()
    {
        return field1;
    }

    /**
     * @param field1 the field1 to set
     */
    public void setField1(String field1)
    {
        this.field1 = field1;
    }

    /**
     * @return the field3
     */
    public int getField3()
    {
        return field3;
    }

    /**
     * @param field3 the field3 to set
     */
    public void setField3(int field3)
    {
        this.field3 = field3;
    }

    /**
     * @return the field2
     */
    public CustomObject getField2()
    {
        return field2;
    }

    /**
     * @param field2 the field2 to set
     */
    public void setField2(CustomObject field2)
    {
        this.field2 = field2;
    }
}
```

> CustomObject Class

```
/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class CustomObject
{

    private String name;
    private int number;

    public CustomObject(String name, int number)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
    }

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the number
     */
    public int getNumber()
    {
        return number;
    }

    /**
     * @param number the number to set
     */
    public void setNumber(int number)
    {
        this.number = number;
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is what I ended up doing, but instead of a helper class, I just added a function in my controller.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just creating a helper function by doing the following:

```
public TreeItem<String> createNode(MyObject obj) {
        TreeItem<String> node = null;
        if(obj != null) {
            node = new TreeItem<String>("MyObject:" + obj.getId());
            node.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<String>("Field1: "+ obj.getField1()));
            node.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<String>("Field2: "+ obj.getField2()));
            node.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<String>("Field3: "+ obj.getField3()));
        }
}
```